# displaying data in Jupyter pivottable.js

Tags: python, jupyter, pivottable.js

I have a pandas DataFrame with  3 columns : `product`, `region`, and `cost`.

I want to display a pivot table using pivottable.js in a Jupyter notebook such that `product` are rows, `region` are columns and `cost` are values.

I have tried :

```
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'region':['N', 'S', 'W', 'E', 'N', 'S', 'W', 'E'], 
                   'product':['P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2'],
                   'cost':[10, 13, 17, 28, 29, 23, 17, 18]})
pivot_ui(df, rows=['product'], cols=['region'], values=['cost'])
```

But this does not work, since there does not exist a `values` attribute for `pivot_ui()`.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that this function doesn't accept a `values` kwarg, but rather `vals`.

The second issue you'll face is that you'll need to specify an aggregation function (the default is `Count`) to summarize your values. This is sort of similar to the `pandas` pivot table's `aggfunc` argument. If you expect to only have a single value then something like `pivot_ui(df, rows=['product'], cols=['region'], vals=['cost'], aggregatorName='First')` should do the trick.

By way of explanation, your code above is just providing the `Count` of input records per cell. `Count` doesn't accept any arguments, so passing in `vals` on its own won't change that. `First` does accept arguments, so passing in `vals=['cost']` will cause each cell to contain the first value of `cost` (ordered via "natural sort") per cell.